# MarkoTag not valid

Tags: typescript, webpack, marko

I have a java application which is serving up a react ts app on the client side. I want to integrate marko into my application in order to access some marko components.

I'm trying to follow [a guide on how to add marko to my webpack config](https://markojs.com/docs/webpack/) but all my attempt are being met with

> You gave us a visitor for the node type MarkoTag but it's not a valid type

from searching, this seems to be an issue with either typescript or babel. But unsure what.

Is it possible to add a marko component to a react application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you have multiple versions of `@babel/types` in your module graph.

The error is from `@babel/traverse` which checks AST node type using `@babel/types`, but if there are multiple copies and the version that Marko's compiler registers its node types with is not the same one used by `@babel/traverse`, it sees them as invalid nodes.